# Swiper ignoring delay

Tags: swiper.js

I am trying to use delay on swiper but it is ignoring the parameter, I try by changing the number of milliseconds but nothing changes.

maybe it's some kind of conflict here my website : https://www.warriorshop.com.br/

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
    },
    loop: true,
    speed: 4000,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 20000,
    },
});
```